# How to enable EMI option using Razorpay Hosted checkout form?

Tags: razorpay

I'm integrating Payment Gateway as Razorpay Hosted checkout form in our project.In this form fields i don't mention any payment method `(prefill['method'])`, but it's showing `card`, `netbanking`, `wallet`, `upi` without emi options.  How can I enable emi option?

Comment: EMI is enabled only over certain amounts. What amount are you trying with? Try passing `550000` as the amount.

Comment: i tried this amount(550000) but not showing emi option

Comment: Can you post the options you have used to initialize Checkout? Please mask the key and order IDs.